# unable to start Hive services

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to start hive services in my system,but its getting Failed.
Hive server2 and Hive Metastore services are started.

> [root@master conf]# sudo service hive-server start Failed to start
>   Hive Server. Return value: 1               [FAILED]

Below is configuration for hive-site.xml

```
<!-- hive properties -->
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://master/metastore</value>
    <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>mypassword</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://master:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>


<property>
    <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>support concu</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.enforce.bucketing</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>enforce bukketing</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
    <value>nonstrict</value>
    <description>enforce bukceting</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.txn.manager</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager</value>
    <description>transaction manager</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.compactor.initiator.on</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>compactor</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.compactor.worker.threads</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>worker thread</description>
</property>
```

Following is the error log:

```
[root@master hive]# cat hive-server.out

Starting Hive Thrift Server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Is there any issue with the thrift server?

Please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10000</value>
  <description>TCP port number to listen on, default 10000</description>
</property>
```

In hive-site.xml

Comment: And what does it do? Explain more widely

Comment: I referred from this site
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2

Comment: You're on SO. Take a time and read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)